# How to setting php with html table specific

Tags: php, mysql

I had a problem that I can't make my php table as I wanted...
Here is my data and I selected result like below table:

```
SELECT Class, Subject, Category, 
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-01", 1, 0)) AS _01_, 
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-02", 1, 0)) AS _02_, 
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-03", 1, 0)) AS _03_, SUM(IF(Class != 'BLANK',1,0)) Total
FROM tblClass WHERE DateClass LIKE '2018-06%'
```

```
|Class |Subject |Category|_01_|_02_|_03_|Total|
|1     |Hardware|Printer |1   |0   |3   |4    |
|1     |Hardware|HDD     |0   |2   |1   |3    |
|1     |Software|PHP     |3   |0   |0   |3    |
|1     |Software|vb.net  |0   |4   |2   |6    |
|2     |Software|PHP     |9   |0   |1   |10   |
|2     |Hardware|PSU     |10  |1   |9   |20   |
```

But I want the table become:

```
|Class |Subject |Category|_01_|_02_|_03_|Total|
|1     |Hardware|Printer |1   |0   |  3 |4    |
|      |        |HDD     |0   |2   |1   |3    |
|      |Software|PHP     |3   |0   |0   |3    |
|      |        |vb.net  |0   |4   |2   |6    |
|2     |Software|PHP     |9   |0   |1   |10   |
|      |Hardware|PSU     |10  |1   |9   |20   |
```

Is that someone can guide me?

PHP Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Class</td>
<td>Subject</td>
<td>Category</td>
<td>_01</td>
<td>_02_</td>
<td>_03_</td>
<td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(servername,username,password,db);
$query = $mysqli->query("
SELECT Class, Subject, Category,
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-01", 1, 0)) AS _01_, 
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-02", 1, 0)) AS _02_, 
SUM(IF(DateClass = "2018-06-03", 1, 0)) AS _03_, SUM(IF(Class != 'BLANK',1,0)) Total
FROM tblClass WHERE DateClass LIKE '2018-06%'
");
foreach($query as $result){
echo "<td>".$result['Class']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['Subject']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['Category']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['_01_']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['_02_']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['_03_']."</td>"
echo "<td>".$result['Total']."</td>"
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

there the php code, I'm so sorry for mistake...

Comment: Please show your existing PHP code and some edits can be suggested to make the table look like you want it to.

Comment: Hi @Nick, there i was add the php code... Please advise

Comment: @senseikoro That is not the way we do it in stackoverflow.com! But let me tell you what you should do. In your loop, you should keep the last row class name, and then at beginning of adding each row, compare the new class with the old one. Like this maybe: http://collabedit.com/6mupy  But this will fill the table with empty cells, where the class name is absent. The next step would be changing the way you output. You just echo it now, but you should keep it in a buffer, and instead of creating empty cells, you should add a rowspan to the td you create. That is why I added a counter.

Comment: But changing all of the stuff takes a lot of time for me, and this is not even considered an answer my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try follow code. I hope the following code will help you in getting your result. Let me know if you are facing any issue or found any modification in this.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5", cellspacing="0">
<?php 

$cls = null;
$sub = null;
$cat = null;

foreach($query as $result){

    if($cls != $result['Class'] && $cls != null) {

        $sub = null;
        $cat = null;
    }

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo ($cls != $result['Class'] ? $result['Class'] : '');
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo ($sub != $result['Subject'] ? $result['Subject'] : '');
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo ($cat != $result['Category'] ? $result['Category'] : '');
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result['_01_'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result['_02_'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result['_03_'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result['Total'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $cls = $result['Class'];
    $sub = $result['Subject'];  
    $cat = $result['Category']; 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello @Nick, thank you for your advise... It's really working... Thanks

Comment: Don't thank me, thank @HirenJoshi, I just corrected a couple of minor errors in their code.

Comment: Hi @Hiren Joshi Thank you for your kindness to guide me...
Hi Nick, btw thanks too

Comment: Hey Sensei, you are welcome and thanks Nick for your changes.